# S3 + Cloudfront slow

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront

I use s3 and cloudfront for my domain (https://punity.de) and its loading so slow compared to other cdns.

I enabled all edge locations, it says hit from cloudfront, but when you delete cache it loads sometimes 200ms - 2 seconds...

When I try to reach my s3 bucket, its much faster than the cloudfront production website (punity.de)

https://prnt.sc/u4igrb all the time...

I tried this for the last days, to also ensure that it don't relays on peak times.

Comment: I'm in Australia. I went to your website. The first load took a bit of time. Subsequent loads (in different) browsers all went very quickly, suggesting that the first access cached the content in CloudFront and subsequent requests were served from the cache.

Comment: i ended up using cloudflare, its 10x faster.